# Flutter where to place the sound and image icon for Google FCM notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send push notifications to devices using FCM but I am not sure where to put the sound or image file

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCI...",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon",
      "sound" : "mySound"
    }
  }
```